Title: How to Create Website-Specific Customer Attributes in Adobe Commerce (Magento 2)?
I am working on a Magento 2 project where I need to create customer attributes that have different values for different websites. By default, Magento 2 customer attributes are scoped globally, but I need them to be website-specific.

I'm not sure this is even possible actually. Your attribute can be attribute set specific but attribute set are global to the customer.
On product you can specify on the attribute something like
'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, 
But that's for products I doubt it works for customer.
I think what you need to do is simply load the customer in the proper store. Then it will have the proper attribute value. And it kinda make sense that's not possible as the customer itself do not have any mention to a scope; you can set him an attribute to get his scope but you can't switch scope like you are doing with products or custom entities.
What you can also do is alter the way you fill or get the attribute depending on the website.
I think some pretty good example could be taxvat ? It's usually on attribute only for b2b customers...though..it's still appearing in the customer backend even if your customer is b2c
